# Else keyword in non void function in C++

Tags: c++

Can we ignore else keyword and write rest of the code which is not if's part in non void or int return type function as shown in below example .What difference does it make ?

```
int searhLL(Node *head, int x){
Node *curr = head;
int pos = 1;
while (curr != NULL)
{
    if (curr->data == x)
        return pos;
    else   // can we remove else keyword here ? 
    {
        pos++;
        curr = curr->next;
    }
}
return -1;}
```

**Another Example**

```
Node *delHead(Node *head){
if(head==NULL)return NULL;
else   // ?
{
Node *temp = head->next;
delete head;
}
return temp;
```

}

Comment: Semantically, there is no difference. It's a purely stylistic choice.

Comment: Yes, it is entirely a style / choice.

Comment: Yes, do that if you like. It doesn't matter whether the function returns a value or returns `void`; you can always return early.